# Adding Content in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am new to drupal and im on practicing the product. How would someone add a button on a page using the WYSIWYG without having to have any HTML or CSS knowledge. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this markup in your WYSIWYG in Plain text mode.

```
<a href="#" class="button">TEXT</a>
```

Then swich to Full HTML and save page.

Then you can add some styles.

Comment: yeah but what if you didn't have any html or css knowledge. A thought cms was designed for people who don't have any web design knowledge.

Comment: You also can add link and styles to any text with WYSIWYG "insert link" and "Edit CSS Style" tools.